# Remove “Choose An Option” on Product Variation & Auto Select Instead

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, dropdown, customization

I have a specific dropdown field on variable products on my WooCommerce site that only ever has one option available. Example: the customer chooses the item “type”, then “color”, and finally “part number”, where “part number” dropdown always has just one option.

I want to configure the site to remove the choose an option requirement from the “part number” dropdown and instead, automatically select the single option available.

Is there a way to do this? It seems that WooCommerce needs an option that allows you to auto select a variation attribute when there is only one possible attribute available for the combination.

Answer (score 4):

Following code solves the purpose:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args','fun_select_default_option',10,1);
function fun_select_default_option( $args)
{

    if(count($args['options']) > 0) //Check the count of available options in dropdown
        $args['selected'] = $args['options'][0];
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: For some reason that's not having any effect. I've inserted it into the functions.php file of my child theme. Is there anything I need to change to target the specific dropdown field?

Comment: check the result of count($args['options'])

Comment: Still can't get it to change the behavior of the dropdowns even when I experiment with different values for the ($args['options']). It still requires me to manually select the option available in the last dropdown. Another way of putting it is that I simply need to remove "choose an option" in all cases and force it to select the first option available.

Comment: What is the value you get on printing count($args['options'])?

Comment: Forgive me for not completely understanding, but how do I determine that? Do you mean I need to check the count of available variation combinations on a specific product?

Comment: add statement echo count($args['options']); before  if(count($args['options']) == 1). it will print the count of available options

Comment: @Aparna_29 Thanks for the code, it works perfectly. I'm using it to set (force) default variation for all products with multiple variations.

Comment: Don't know about this hook. Thanks. But the code doesn't work in all possible cases. For example, if we have two attributes A & B with values a1, a2, a3 & b1, b2, b3, and there isn't the variation a1+b1 we will have auto-reset to "Choose an option". So, we need check is variation exist and, probably, its stock status.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [Original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51181479/remove-choose-an-option-from-variable-product-dropdowns-in-woocommerce-3) answer.

So there is 2 different case:

1) Removing this html option completelly**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'filter_dropdown_option_html', 12, 2 );
function filter_dropdown_option_html( $html, $args ) {
    $show_option_none_text = $args['show_option_none'] ? $args['show_option_none'] : __( 'Choose an option', 'woocommerce' );
    $show_option_none_html = '<option value="">' . esc_html( $show_option_none_text ) . '</option>';

    $html = str_replace($show_option_none_html, '', $html);

    return $html;
}
```

Code goes in `function.php` file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

2) Remove only the text "Select an option" (you will have an option without label name):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'filter_dropdown_option_html', 12, 2 );
function filter_dropdown_option_html( $html, $args ) {
    $show_option_none_text = $args['show_option_none'] ? $args['show_option_none'] : __( 'Choose an option', 'woocommerce' );
    $show_option_none_text = esc_html( $show_option_none_text );

    $html = str_replace($show_option_none_text, '', $html);

    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Snippets plugin which can add snipptes to funtion.php without hacking the files. This says if the number of options is 1, show that one option in the dropdown but without removing it as a variable. Use at your own risk, I'm a web designer not really a developer.

My usecase might be different. I have a few thousand products, with 5 different possible combinations. To keep all products the same (especially when importing and exporting) I have 5 variable dropdowns even if a product doesn't really have a variation. This works when the page is loading, I don't think it would work based on a selection of a previous attribute.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args','woo_select_default_option',10,1);

function woo_select_default_option( $args)
{

    if(count($args['options']) == 1) //Ensure product variation isn't empty
        $args['selected'] = $args['options'][0];
    return $args;
}
```